# Vertically centering html entities contained in css :before selectors?

Tags: html, css

I have these elements containing characters:

```
    .Š::before {
        content: "Š";
    }

    .©::before {
        content: "©";
    }

    .§::before {
        content: "§";
    }
```

If I use these like this:

```
    <div style="line-height: 5rem; font-size: 2rem; display: flex; align-items: center">          
    <span class="Š"></span>
    <span class="©"></span>
    <span class="§"></span>
    </div>
```

The Š and the © html entities appear centered but the § entity does not look like it is centered with the © character.

Is there a way to make the html entities look as if they are all centered on a horizontal line going through them?

Comment: No, there isn't. It depends on the font. Technically, they're centered, but the designer wanted them as you see them. The only solution is to apply exceptions to them so they display as you want them to.

Comment: Thats what I thought ... I guess I can hack around it by setting position to relative and moving the top using negative pixels.

Comment: Until someone comes with a device that doesn't have some language pack and the browser will default to some other font and they'll look reaaaaly weird :D. Good luck! Typically, when you get to this type of tinkering, you're likely doing it wrong. There are other aspects of your design which could be changed to make them all look neat and lined up without having to alter their line-height or position. Methinks. Or I might be wrong. You haven't shown a [mcve] so I can't tell..

Comment: Yeah I noticed that hack looks different on displays with different screen resolutions ... so will probably do SVG or something ultimately ...

Comment: For a visual demonstration, see https://jsfiddle.net/samurai_jane/96qsb45h/22/

Comment: Very cool!  Looks legit - Maybe make that the official answer?